# How to change the 'url' and 'src' property via web.config

Tags: javascript, html, css, server

I am using root-relative path for all of 'url' and 'src' properties in HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
My working environment and production server's directoy depth are the same, but the test server is running inside the production server. So everytime I upload a file to the test server I need to rename the path.
I want to make it so that the web.config in the test server add a directory right after the root.

e.g.
What I'm writing == `src="/img/example.jpg"` 
What I want it to be == `src="/added-directoy/img/example.jpg"`

To do this I've tried this with web.config hosted in test server.

```
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect root">
    <match url="(.*)"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/img$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/img/$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://root/hoge/img/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Since the test server is builded inside the production server, I only want to rewrite files uploaded in the test server.

I'm new to server setting so I might be missing bunch of stuff, but can anyone help me?

Additional explanation

The production server and my working environment’s index page's url is `https://example.com/index.html .`
But since the test server is nested inside the  production server, test environment’s url is `https://example.com/test/index.html` .
So, in test environment, path which is intended to set link to `https://example.com/test/img/sample.jpg` access one directory above and gives back `https://example.com/img/sample.jpg`. I wanted to find a way so that I don’t have to add extra `/test/` in src property which will not be used in production server.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to CSS? Why not use `<base href="">`?

Comment: @NicoHaase, thank you very much for your answer.
I’ve tried `<base href="">` but it had no effect on the root relative paths. And since it changes the behavior of links including `#` I don’t really want to use it.

The reason why I put css tag is, because I wanted to change the links in css files such as `background: url(/img/example.jpg)`.
Did I misuse the tag? Sorry if I did. It’s my first time posting here, so I would appreciate any advice.

I've edited my original question. Hope it will clarify.
Thanks in advance